# If the where clause number input is large, it takes too much time to process

Tags: oracle, performance, query-optimization, largenumber

Code:

```
select * 
from(
select /*+ USE_HASH(a b c) */ ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.TRANS_DT DESC, A.TRANS_TM DESC) AS RNUM,
        , a.id
        , ....
        , ....
  from tb_a a, tb_b b, tb_c c
  where a.i_mid = b.i_mid
    and a.txid = c.txid
)
where rnum between 850001 and 900000
```

If the where clause number is small, it is very fast. (for example : where rnum between 1 and 50000).

What can be done?

Comment: Have you tried to execute  `EXPLAIN PLAN XXXX` replacing `XXXX` by your query?

Comment: Is your DBMS oracle or MySQL?

Comment: Why was this tagged with jQuery?

Comment: Offtop. In Oracle you use hint use_hash incorrect way https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2016/03/17/hinting-4/

Comment: I'M using oracle.

Comment: @robert gave you the correct answer: when you need the 50,000 lowest values, you just keep track of 50,000 values; most of the other values are higher than the 50,000th so they are discarded without much effort. There is much more work sorting 900,000 values. IN ADDITION to that fine answer, though: it seems you order by a DATE and a TIME? Since those do not exist independent of each other, one must ask: WHAT DATA TYPE are trans_dt and trans_tm? This smells like a very inefficient data model to begin with (regardless of any queries).

Answer (score 0):

Not a "SQL expert" but it looks to me like you are determining RNUM by `ORDER BY A.TRANS_DT DESC, A.TRANS_TM DESC` which for small numbers such as "1 and 50000" isn't such a big deal as it only needs to determine the 1st 50000 rows, ordered by `A.TRANS_DT` and `A.TRANS_TM`. When you do `850001 and 900000` it has to determine the first 900,000 rows ...

I think implicit in your problem is the fact that you are ordering by these two fields, and applying a window based on the row-number from this order. If the order were already known it wouldn't be as slow. I would suggest adding an index to the table on `A.TRANS_DT` and `A.TRANS_TM`, such that this ordering is already readily known.